# Androidのtextboxの入力の初期状態をアルファベットにしたい

Tags: android

Androidでtextboxをクリックすると下からキーボードが出てきますが、これの初期状態が日本語入力になってしまいます。最初にアルファベット入力の状態にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

Androidアプリの話と仮定します。
[`EditText.inputType`](http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-tips-20-edittext-inputtype/)プロパティで入力モードを指定できます。

記事にもある通り入力制限の挙動はIMEにより異なるため、別途Validationの実装が必要です。